# Jquery alert isn't working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to understand how jquery works with click events. So I created a simple mvc 3 app, then added a button to the view. I created a simple js file. However when I click it, it doesn't popup the alert.

Here is my code in the view:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="../../Scripts/first.js"></script>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<div>
 <p style="text-align: center;">
            <input type="button" id="steps" name="steps" value="Next >" />
        </p>
</div>
```

Here is my complete js file:

```
$("#steps").click(function () {
alert("hola!");
});
```

Any input would greatly appreciated, as I have very limited javascript/jquery knowledge.

Comment: Do you have a `<script>` tag that loads jQuery?

Comment: any console errors? if youre using chrome, press f12 and check the error in the bottom right hand corner of the window which opens.

Comment: Your code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/nHfn6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned it was the "complete" js file.

You need to wrap the jQuery code around a `.ready()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $("#steps").click(function () {
     alert("hola!");
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I am just beginning to learn jquery. Seems to be a lot harder to grasp then .net.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the document is **ready** by using either of these 2 **functions**

```
$(function() {

   // Code here...

});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Code here...

});
```

**Like this**

```
$(function(){

   $("#steps").click(function () {
      alert("hola!");
   });

});
```

**Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/**

If you don't do this, it's likely that you are adding the `click` event when the element doesn't exist yet.

**PS: Also make sure you are actually including jQuery**

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a runtime error.  Your JS is attempting to reference an element that doesn't exist at the point of the code being read by the browser - your `button`.  So, to combat that, either put that code in a `$(document).ready()` function, or place it at the *bottom* of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/FMy65/

Did you load jQuery correctly? You need to load the jQuery library in order to use it. You can do this by including `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>` at the top of your page. 
That's using the CDN (the script is hosted elsewhere) or you can download it and host it on your server (http://code.jquery.com/).